# Downloaded Stanford POS Tagger Got Different Results with Online Stanford Parser

Tags: stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I downloaded the lastest Stanford POS Tagger from https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.html , then use the following code to get the pos tag of a sentence:

```
jar = './stanford_postagger/stanford-postagger-3.9.1.jar'
model = './stanford_postagger/models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger'
pos_tagger = StanfordPOSTagger(model, jar)
text = nltk.word_tokenize('How much did the Dow rise?')
stanford_pos = pos_tagger.tag(text)
```

The output for this sentence is:

[('How', 'WRB'), ('much', 'RB'), ('did', 'VBD'), ('the', 'DT'), ('Dow', 'NNP'), ('rise', 'NN'), ('?', '.')]

which is a wrong output -- interpreting the last verb as noun.

But the online parser at http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp gives the right pos tag:

How/WRB
much/JJ
did/VBD
the/DT
dow/NN
rise/VB
?/.

could someone tell me why these two give different results?